# Picasso library for Android behaves inconsistently when called repeatedly for ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I am using the Picasso image loading library for Android in my project. I noticed this bug when I saw it loading the wrong image into an ImageView in an ArrayAdapter that utilizes the ViewHolder pattern.

Here is the crux of the bug, which I can now repro consistently in a test Activity I created. I call this method in onCreate:

```
private void refreshImageView() {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.image);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        new Picasso.Builder(this).build()
        .load(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.1:4568/images/red.png"))
        .placeholder(R.drawable.silhouette)
        .noFade()
        .into(imageView);
    }

    new Picasso.Builder(this).build()
    .load(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.1:4568/images/blue.png"))
    .placeholder(R.drawable.silhouette)
    .noFade()
    .into(imageView);
}
```

I moreover added some debug output to ImageViewAction.java. Here is what I added:

```
String str = bitmapToString(result);
Log.i("PicassoDebug", String.format("Complete and loading %s into %s", str.substring(str.length() - 20, str.length() - 1), target));
```

And here is the output:

```
12-10 17:08:37.061: I/PicassoDebug(16411): Complete and loading nbAAAAAElF
12-10 17:08:37.061: I/PicassoDebug(16411): TkSuQmCC into android.widget.ImageView{42067f38 V.ED.... ........ 333,482-466,615 #7f08003b app:id/image}
12-10 17:08:37.121: I/PicassoDebug(16411): Complete and loading nbAAAAAElF
12-10 17:08:37.121: I/PicassoDebug(16411): TkSuQmCC into android.widget.ImageView{42067f38 V.ED.... ......ID 333,482-466,615 #7f08003b app:id/image}
12-10 17:08:37.171: I/PicassoDebug(16411): Complete and loading nbAAAAAElF
12-10 17:08:37.171: I/PicassoDebug(16411): TkSuQmCC into android.widget.ImageView{42067f38 V.ED.... ......ID 333,482-466,615 #7f08003b app:id/image}
12-10 17:08:37.221: I/PicassoDebug(16411): Complete and loading nbAAAAAElF
12-10 17:08:37.221: I/PicassoDebug(16411): TkSuQmCC into android.widget.ImageView{42067f38 V.ED.... ......ID 333,482-466,615 #7f08003b app:id/image}
12-10 17:08:37.281: D/dalvikvm(16411): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1766K, 22% free 16413K/20988K, paused 32ms, total 33ms
12-10 17:08:37.281: I/PicassoDebug(16411): Complete and loading ewAAAAASUVORK5CYII= into android.widget.ImageView{42067f38 V.ED.... ......ID 333,482-466,615 #7f08003b app:id/image}
12-10 17:08:37.341: I/PicassoDebug(16411): Complete and loading nbAAAAAElF
12-10 17:08:37.341: I/PicassoDebug(16411): TkSuQmCC into android.widget.ImageView{42067f38 V.ED.... ........ 333,482-466,615 #7f08003b app:id/image}
12-10 17:08:37.391: I/PicassoDebug(16411): Complete and loading nbAAAAAElF
12-10 17:08:37.391: I/PicassoDebug(16411): TkSuQmCC into android.widget.ImageView{42067f38 V.ED.... ......ID 333,482-466,615 #7f08003b app:id/image}
12-10 17:08:37.441: I/PicassoDebug(16411): Complete and loading nbAAAAAElF
12-10 17:08:37.441: I/PicassoDebug(16411): TkSuQmCC into android.widget.ImageView{42067f38 V.ED.... ......ID 333,482-466,615 #7f08003b app:id/image}
12-10 17:08:37.501: I/PicassoDebug(16411): Complete and loading nbAAAAAElF
12-10 17:08:37.501: I/PicassoDebug(16411): TkSuQmCC into android.widget.ImageView{42067f38 V.ED.... ......ID 333,482-466,615 #7f08003b app:id/image}
12-10 17:08:37.551: I/PicassoDebug(16411): Complete and loading nbAAAAAElF
12-10 17:08:37.551: I/PicassoDebug(16411): TkSuQmCC into android.widget.ImageView{42067f38 V.ED.... ........ 333,482-466,615 #7f08003b app:id/image}
12-10 17:08:37.601: I/PicassoDebug(16411): Complete and loading nbAAAAAElF
12-10 17:08:37.601: I/PicassoDebug(16411): TkSuQmCC into android.widget.ImageView{42067f38 V.ED.... ......ID 333,482-466,615 #7f08003b app:id/image}
```

The line that starts with "nbAA" is red.png, the line that starts with "ewAA" is blue.png. As you can see, some of the load requests for red completed after blue, and so red was shown instead of blue.

Is there a bug in picasso? Or is this "by design"? If it is by design, what is the proposed design pattern for using Picasso in ArrayAdapters, which frequently will call getView() repeatedly on the same item before updating?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

When I called new Picasso.Builder(this).build(), I was creating a new object with a new targetToAction hashmap that didn't include the previous requests.

The correct approach to solving this problem is as follows:

```
private void refreshImageView() {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.image);

    Picasso p = new Picasso.Builder(this).build();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        p.load(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.1:4568/images/red.png"))
        .placeholder(R.drawable.silhouette)
        .noFade()
        .into(imageView);
    }

    p.load(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.1:4568/images/blue.png"))
    .placeholder(R.drawable.silhouette)
    .noFade()
    .into(imageView);
}
```

My mistake was in thinking of Picasso as a global singleton. It is not.

Comment: Use `Picasso.with`. Don't make a new instance every time you need to load images!

Comment: Right...in my actual code I had to replace the downloader with my own custom downloader that used a custom file cache. That's why I did the new Picasso.Builder method...but in so doing, I lost the benefit of the global singleton in Picasso.with and hence hit these kinds of bugs. I now use a single Picasso instance per activity and things are fine once more.

Comment: Use a single instance in the entire app, not per-activity.

Comment: If I only use "Picasso.with..." in every activity in the app, will I be using single instance in the entire app?